# Interpolation inequality - what does it mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose $f_{k} \to f$ strongly in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Let $2 \le 2q < \eta$ where $\eta = \infty$ if $n \le 2$ and $\eta = 2n/(n-2)$ if $n \ge 3$. During a proof, my professor wrote that $\|f_{k}-f\|_{L^{2q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ by interpolation inequality.

I searched the term interpolation inequality on the internet and found a lot of different results. What does it mean in the present context?

**Edit:** Let me add more details about my problem. I am trying to prove the following result: Let $g \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $p > \max\{n/2,1\}$ and suppose $f_{n} \rightharpoonup f$ on $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, meaning that $\langle f_{n}, h\rangle_{L^{2}}+\langle \nabla f_{n},\nabla h\rangle_{L^{2}} \to \langle f, h\rangle_{L^{2}}+\langle \nabla f, \nabla h\rangle_{L^{2}}$ for every $h \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Then:
$$\lim \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g(x)|f_{n}(x)|^{2}dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} g(x)|f(x)|^{2}dx$$

The proof goes like this. Let $q$ be such that $1/p+1/q = 1$. Then, by Hölder and Minkowski inequalities:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|g(x)|||f_{n}(x)|^{2}-|f(x)|^{2}|dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|g(x)||f_{n}(x)-|f(x)|(|f_{n}(x)|+|f(x)|)dx \le \|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2q}}\||f_{n}|+|f|\|_{L^{2q}}\|g\|_{L^{p}} \le \|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2q}}(\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2q}}+\|f\|_{L^{2q}})\|g\|_{L^{p}} \le K\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2q}}$$
and the latter must go to zero by some interpolation inequality.

Comment: I’m guessing this came up somewhere in a proof involving Sobolev spaces? Please include all (more of) the details because as written, there’s no use of $\eta$ anywhere in the hypotheses, so as written, the statement is false. Convergence in a lower Lebesgue space ($L^2$) does not imply convergence in a higher one ($L^{2q}$… even if on a finite-measure space… in fact on a finite measure space, we have the reverse inclusion).

Comment: An interpolation inequality is something like if you’re in two spaces, then you’re in all the ones in between. For example if $1\leq p<q<r\leq\infty$ then $f\in L^p$ and $f\in L^r$ implies $f\in L^q$ and you can prove a suitable bound on the norms; this follows using Holder’s inequality. There are many more sophisticated examples.

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, actually. The sequence $\{f_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ lives in the Sobolev space $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and converges strongly to $f$ in $L^{2}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo in this case, what kind of interpolation inequality should I use?

Comment: Is this part of the proof of Rellich’s theorem? I’m still pretty sure you’re omitting stuff. What have you already proven up till now? What exactly are your assumptions?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I edited the post with all the details of the result I am proving.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By interpolation of $L^p$ spaces (see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/), Lemma 9), we have

$$\|f_k-f\|_{L^{2q}}\leq \|f_k-f\|_{L^\eta}^\theta \|f_k-f\|_{L^2}^{1-\theta}$$

For some exponent $0<\theta<1$ depending on $q$ that’s unimportant here. It now suffices to bound the $L^\eta$ norm of $f_k-f$, which can be derived from the Gagliardo-Nirenberg Sobolev inequality, provided that $n\geq 3$:

$$\|f_k-f\|_{L^\eta} \leq C \|f_k-f\|_{H^1}$$

The right hand side bounded since weakly convergent sequences and their limits are bounded.

However, when $n=2$, i.e. $\eta =\infty$, the Gagliardo-Nirenberg embedding is false, so I’m not sure how that’s supposed to be handled.

Comment: The embedding is true for any $\eta<\infty $ in this case

Comment: I think $\eta = n/(n-2)$ only when $n \ge 3$, and $\eta = \infty$ in any other case, meaning that $f_{k}$ and $f$ are elements of $L^{2}$ and $L^{2q}$ for every $q$. Hence, I is enough to get an $\eta$ greater or equal than $2q$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @LL3.14 are you saying that $H^1$ is embedded in $L^p$ for any $p<2^*=\eta$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, any $p\in [2,2^*)$ (and with $2^*$ included if it not infinity)

Comment: @LL3.14 $p$ can be any *real* number?

Comment: Yes of course, since $L^p \subset L^{p_1}\cap L^{p_2}$ if $p_1\leq p\leq p_2$.